# plm, lagged variables, and fitted values in R

Tags: r, lag, plm

I have a panel dataset and try to use the plm package to estimate a pooled OLS model. Essentially, I am doing two regressions. First, I try to estimate the following equation

```
y(t) = a + (a1 + a2*x1(t-1)) * x2(t) = a + a1*x2(t) + a2*x1(t-1)*x2(t)
```

where (t-1) means that it should be lagged 1 period, and * denotes simple multiplication. I want to extract the fitted term (a1 + a2*x1(t-1)), call it "fit", and then use it in another regression such as

```
z(t) = b + b1*fit(t) + b2*x1(t-1)
```

My panel, df, is unbalanced, and could be the following:

```
Individual Date x1 x2 y
1 2001 0.5 0.2 0.3
1 2002 0.4 0.3 0.4
1 2003 0.6 0.15 0.5
1 2004 0.5 0.25 0.3
2 2002 0.5 0.25 0.1
2 2003 0.6 0.4 0.2
2 2004 0.7 0.7 0.3
```

I try to fit the first regression as follows:

```
df.plm <- plm(y ~ x2 + lag(x1,1):x2, data=df)
```

Will this give me the previously mentioned regression? And, if so, how do I obtain the term from above `(a1 + a2*x1(t-1))`, so that I can use it in the next regression?